# What does その場に広げる means in this context?

Tags: translation, phrases

I was doing some translating work, and I came across this sentence:

> 私はぼんやりとお弁当箱を取り出して、その場に広げた。

I was sure that the first part of the sentence means "I took my lunch box out absent-mindedly", but I can't come to a satisfactory conclusion with the part after the comma.

At first, I thought it was just "opening it (the lunch box)" or something along those lines, but time after time I feel unsatisfied about it.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You might be confused with because you are not cognizant of the bento-box is wrapped with cloth so-called ["Furoshiki"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furoshiki).

Due to this, you might feel need to express the process of "unwrapping".

So, in my opinion,「その場に広げた」would be translated into *"unwrap the box and spread out (for eating) on the spot"*.